# Samsung Note 8 Firmware

Tags: device-firmware

I'm just new to android as i have been using ios for all this time, my question is, I have recently bought a Note 8 in the UK, due to cost and I'm now back home in Australia, can I change the samsung firmware from the UK to AU Firmware if i have been able to download the AU version?

Comment: Do you ask out of a real need to do so? Doing this may be more trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 0):

Both UK and Australia are slated to get the SM-N950F (international) variant, so theoretically you are free to change the firmware. Firmware for this variant is available on [SamMobile](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-note8/SM-N950F/), where you can see both UK and Australia firmware listed.

Comment: Additionally: why you'd want to change the firmware, though? It's true that the baseband might be optimised for the region using specific firmware, but aside from that, different firmware are not much more than different sets of carrier apps and locales.